# How to deeply search php object and pull all instances of a certain property?

Tags: php

I'm having difficulty finding a good solution or a previous question for this since it's difficult to put into words, but I have a json object here:

```
{

    "type":"template",
    "customStyle":false,
    "preheaderVisible":true,
    "titleText":"Email Template",
    "mainBlocks":{
        "type":"blocks",
        "blocks":[
            {
                "type":"singleArticleBlock",
                "image":{
                    "type":"image",
                    "src":"/template/image/logo-large.png",
                    "url":"http://example.com/",
                    "alt":""
                },
                "longText":"\n <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries <a href=\"\">Vokalia and Consonantia</a>, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>\n ",
                "buttonLink":{
                    "type":"link",
                    "text":"BUTTON",
                    "url":"http://example.com/"
                }
            },
            {
                "type":"tripleArticleBlock",
                "leftImage":{
                    "type":"image",
                    "src":"/template/image/logo-small.png",
                    "url":"http://example.com/",
                    "alt":""
                },
                "leftLongText":"\n <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries <a href=\"\">Vokalia and Consonantia</a>, there live the blind texts. </p>\n ",
                "leftButtonLink":{
                    "type":"buttonLink",
                    "text":"BUTTON",
                    "url":"http://example.com/"
                },
                "middleImage":{
                    "type":"image",
                    "src":"/template/image/logo-small.png",
                    "url":"http://example.com/",
                    "alt":""
                },
                "middleLongText":"\n <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries <a href=\"\">Vokalia and Consonantia</a>, there live the blind texts. </p>\n ",
                "middleButtonLink":{
                    "type":"buttonLink",
                    "text":"BUTTON",
                    "url":"http://example.com/"
                },
                "rightImage":{
                    "type":"image",
                    "src":"",
                    "url":"http://example.com/",
                    "alt":""
                },
                "rightLongText":"\n <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries <a href=\"\">Vokalia and Consonantia</a>, there live the blind texts. </p>\n ",
                "rightButtonLink":{
                    "type":"buttonLink",
                    "text":"BUTTON",
                    "url":"http://example.com/"
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to get every `url` property, regardless of the nest depth or sub-object it's in. So it could be the url for an `image` or `leftButtonLink` and at any depth. I figured there's got to be an easy "give me all props called x" function. What's the most efficient way to do this in php?

Comment: _I figured there's got to be an easy "give me all props called x" function_ There is not, not until you write one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) should work well for this.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$urls = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($value, $key) use (&$urls) {
    if ($key == 'url') $urls[] = $value;
});
```

Be sure to decode to arrays rather than objects by setting the second parameter of `json_decode`.

This won't tell you what the URL is *for*, though, if that matters. (e.g. `image`, `leftButtonLink`, etc.) This is just an easy "give me all the props called x" function.

Comment: Just the kind of thing I was looking for.  I have to admit, my knowledge of the many php array manipulation functions is lacking, so thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, PHP has a ton of array functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, try something like this

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$urls = array();
r_search($data);

function r_search($array) {
  global $urls;
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      r_search($value);
    } else if ($key === 'url') {
      $urls[] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

There may also be a better way without globals.  do some searching for recursive array search.

Comment: I was literally typing out almost this same thing when yours post. +1 for speedy response. The only difference I had was my url array was not a global and was just passed through the recursion

Comment: replace $key == 'url' with $key === 'url' otherwise this condition will be true for first element in array  (with index 0) 0 == 'url'

Comment: @AndreyYerokhin I don't follow, but I know it won't hurt either